# How to sort XmlNodeList when hierarchy is different in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

1) Can you please tell me how to sort code tag value as per given attribute value.

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Example >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Input:

```
<category>
        <code type="pub">e00001</code>
        <title>cat1</title>
        <ranking>0</ranking>
    </category>
    <category>
        <span>
           <code type="pub">e00004</code>
        </span>
        <title>cat2</title>
        <ranking>1</ranking>
    </category>
    <category>
        <code type="pub">e00003</code>
        <title>awe</title>
        <ranking>10</ranking>
    </category>
    <category>
        <span>
           <code type="pub">e00002</code>
        </span>
        <title>zrt</title>
        <ranking>6</ranking>
    </category>
```

Output:

```
<category>
        <code type="pub">e00001</code>
        <title>cat1</title>
        <ranking>0</ranking>
    </category>
    <category>
        <span>
           <code type="pub">e00002</code>
        </span>
        <title>zrt</title>
        <ranking>6</ranking>
    </category>
    <category>
        <code type="pub">e00003</code>
        <title>awe</title>
        <ranking>10</ranking>
    </category>
    <category>
        <span>
           <code type="pub">e00004</code>
        </span>
        <title>cat2</title>
        <ranking>1</ranking>
    </category>
```

2) Another condition:

Is it possible for this xml data?

please check below example and let me know how to sorting this xml data

```
<root>
     <category>
        <code type='pub'>e00001</code>
        <title>cat1</title>
        <ranking>0</ranking>
     </category>
     <category>
         <span>
            <code type='pub'>e00004</code>
         </span>
                 <title>cat2</title>
     <ranking>1</ranking>
     </category>
     <Product>
         <category>
             <span>
                 <code type='pub'>e00002</code>
             </span>
             <title>cat3</title>
             <ranking>2</ranking>
         </category>
         <category>
                 <code type='pub'>e00005</code>
             <title>awe3</title>
             <ranking>11</ranking>
        </category>
     </Product>
     <Product>
     <category>
         <code type='pub'>e00003</code>
         <title>awe</title>
         <ranking>10</ranking>
     </category>
    </Product>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<root>
     <category>
         <code type='pub'>e00001</code>
         <title>cat1</title>
         <ranking>0</ranking>
     </category>
     <Product>
         <category>
             <span>
                 <code type='pub'>e00002</code>
             </span>
             <title>cat3</title>
             <ranking>2</ranking>
         </category>
     </Product>
     <Product>
     <category>
         <code type='pub'>e00003</code>
         <title>awe</title>
         <ranking>10</ranking>
     </category>
     </Product>
     <category>
         <span>
            <code type='pub'>e00004</code>
         </span>
         <title>cat2</title>
         <ranking>1</ranking>
     </category>
     <Product>
         <category>
                 <code type='pub'>e00005</code>
             <title>awe3</title>
             <ranking>11</ranking>
         </category>
     </Product>  
</root>
```

3)Condition:

Hi,
please check below Input xml data and let me know how to sorting this xml data.

**Input:**

```
<root>
 <category>
    <code type='pub'>e00001</code>
    <title>test334</title>
    <ranking>240</ranking>
 </category>
 <category>
     <span>
        <code type='pub'>e00007</code>
     </span>
             <title>test76</title>
 <ranking>14</ranking>
 </category>
 <Product>
     <Product-subject-title>
     <subject>IN BRIEF</subject>
     </Product-subject-title>
     <category>
         <span>
             <code type='pub'>e00004</code>
         </span>
         <title>test3</title>
         <ranking>52</ranking>
     </category>
     <category>
             <code type='pub'>e00003</code>
         <title>test6</title>
         <ranking>117</ranking>
    </category>
    <category>
             <code type='pub'>e00006</code>
         <title>test4</title>
         <ranking>116</ranking>
    </category>
 </Product>
 <Product>
 <Product-subject-title>
     <subject>BIOLOGY ARTICLE</subject>
 </Product-subject-title>
 <category>
     <code type='pub'>e00005</code>
     <title>test28</title>
     <ranking>10</ranking>
 </category>
  <category>
     <code type='pub'>e00002</code>
     <title>test34</title>
     <ranking>160</ranking>
 </category>
</Product>
```

**Output:**

```
<root>
     <category>
        <code type='pub'>e00001</code>
        <title>test334</title>
        <ranking>240</ranking>
     </category>
     <Product>
     <Product-subject-title>
         <subject>BIOLOGY ARTICLE</subject>
     </Product-subject-title>
         <category>
         <code type='pub'>e00002</code>
         <title>test34</title>
         <ranking>160</ranking>
         </category>
     </Product>
     <Product>
     <Product-subject-title>
         <subject>IN BRIEF</subject>
     </Product-subject-title>
         <category>
             <code type='pub'>e00003</code>
             <title>test6</title>
             <ranking>117</ranking>
         </category>
         <category>
             <span>
                 <code type='pub'>e00004</code>
             </span>
             <title>test3</title>
             <ranking>52</ranking>
         </category>
     </Product>  
     <Product>
     <Product-subject-title>
         <subject>BIOLOGY ARTICLE</subject>
     </Product-subject-title>
         <category>
             <code type='pub'>e00005</code>
             <title>test28</title>
             <ranking>10</ranking>
         </category>
     </Product>
     <Product>
     <Product-subject-title>
         <subject>IN BRIEF</subject>
     </Product-subject-title>
         <category>
             <code type='pub'>e00006</code>
             <title>test4</title>
             <ranking>116</ranking>
         </category>
     </Product>
     <category>
         <span>
            <code type='pub'>e00007</code>
         </span>
         <title>test76</title>
         <ranking>14</ranking>
     </category>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try xml linq.  I added a Root tag to allow the sort to work

Option 1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication48
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement root = doc.Elements("Root").FirstOrDefault();

            List<XElement> descendants = root.Elements().ToList();
            descendants = descendants.OrderBy(x => (string)x.Descendants("code").FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

            root.ReplaceNodes(descendants);
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication48
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement root = doc.Elements("root").FirstOrDefault();

            List<XElement> products = root.Elements("Product").ToList();
            for (int i = products.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                XElement product = products[i];
                List < XElement > newProducts = new List<XElement>();
                if (product.Elements("category").Count() > 1)
                {
                    foreach (XElement category in product.Elements("category"))
                    {
                        XElement newProduct = new XElement("Product", category);
                        newProducts.Add(newProduct);
                    }
                    product.ReplaceWith(newProducts);
                }
            }

            List<XElement> descendants = root.Elements().ToList();
            descendants = descendants.OrderBy(x => (string)x.Descendants("code").FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

            root.ReplaceNodes(descendants);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi,

Please check above question, i have given some another example of xml data.
Is it possible for sorting and how?

Comment: What is different about 2nd example?

Comment: please check above example with desired output

Comment: You want more than a sort because you want only one category under each product.  The output you posted is inconsistent because the first category is not under a product.

Comment: yeah....i know...but can we sort it...please tell me....because i really need that solution

Comment: I have two application,In First aaplication ill find only category and another application ill find category and product

Comment: yes its work for first application but i want solution for another application i.e. i given you already please check above another condition...

Comment: Hi jdweng sir,

kindly check above new updated condition and can you please tell me how to sorting it

Comment: Why is e00003 and e00004 handled one way and e00006 handled differently?

Comment: hello sir 
Is there any solution?

Comment: I don't know what you want.  Initially e0003, e0004, and e0006 were sibling (had same parent).  Now e0003 and e0004 are siblings and e0006 was moved.  Not sure why e0006 is different from e0003 and e0004

Comment: Sir its requirement so that's why i need it

Comment: I not questioning that it is needed.  I just don't know how to automatically do it.  I don't know why e006 is being handled differently from e003 and e004.  You may have a typo in the example you posted.